# Node Modules: Function call within Module does not work

Tags: node-modules

In the following snippet the call

```
ifDirectoryExistsNot(folderName + dataType)
```

ends in an

```
ReferenceError: ifDirectoryExistsNot is not defined
```

Do you know why that is?

```
var Folder = {
  deleteRecursively: (exportFromCosmosPath) => {
      const child_process = require ('child_process')
      const dirToRemove = exportFromCosmosPath
      const k = child_process.spawn('bash')
      k.stdin.end(`rm -rf "${dirToRemove}"`)
      k.once('exit', code => {
        // check the exit code
        // now you are done
      })
  },
  ifDirectoryExists: () => { 
    fs.existsSync
  },
  ifDirectoryExistsNot: (folderName, dataType) => {
    if (negateFunction(fs.existsSync)){
      console.log('creating dir..... ' + folderName + " " + dataType )
      fs.ensureDirSync(folderName, dataType)
    }
  },
  negateFunction: () => {
    return function(x) {
      return !func(x)
    }
  },
  ensureThatDirectoryExists: (folderName, dataType) => {
    ifDirectoryExistsNot(folderName + dataType)
  }
}



// my Code:
Folder.deleteRecursively('data/*')
Folder.ensureThatDirectoryExists('data/exportFromCosmos/', 'DEFAULT')
Folder.ensureThatDirectoryExists('data/uploadToBlobStorage/', dataType)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One has to call ModuleName.Function() even from within modules.

In my case neither function() name nor this.functionname() worked.

But Modulename.Functionname() is the solution.

So this is the solution

```
ensureThatDirectoryExists: (folderName, dataType) => {
  Folder.ifDirectoryExistsNot(folderName, dataType)
}
```